# How do I read in all checkbox values?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form (using HtmlService) that has some checkboxes. When it gets submitted it's supposed to email the contents. Everything works with the exemption of the checkboxes values. Only the first checkbox value is sent. What am I doing wrong? I've added a sample code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
<form name=“some-form” action="<?= appUrl ?>" method="post”>
<input type=“hidden” name=“form_name” value=“send_form”>
<label>Your Name</label>
<input type=“text” name=“name”>
<label>Your Email</label>
<input type=“text” name=“email”>
<label>Favorite Colors</label>
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“blue”>Blue<br/>
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“red”>Red<br/>
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“yellow”>Yellow<br/>
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“green”>Green<br/>

<input type=“submit” value=“Send Form”>

</form>



// post function

function doPost(e)
{

    var evaluated = undefined;

    //check if right form and call send function
    if(e.parameter.form_name == “send_form”)
    {

        evaluated = sendForm(e)

    }

   return evaluated;

}


// send function

function sendForm(e)
{

    // data from form
    var name = e.parameter.name;
    var email = e.parameter.email;
    var favorite_colors = e.parameter.favorite_colors;


    // create and send message
    var to = “some-email@gmail.com”;
    var subject = “New form response”;
    var body = “A new form was completed” +
           “Name: “ + name +
           “Email: “ + email +
                   “Favorite Colors: “ + email;


    MailApp.SendEmail(to, subject, body);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you were using different var names like this :

```
...
<label>Favorite Colors</label><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='favorite_colors1' value='blue'>Blue<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='favorite_colors2' value='red'>Red<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='favorite_colors3' value='yellow'>Yellow<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name='favorite_colors4' value='green'>Green<br/>
...
```

and in code :

```
function sendForm(e){
  var name = e.parameter.name;
  var email = e.parameter.email;
  var favorite_colors1 = e.parameter.favorite_colors1;
  var favorite_colors2 = e.parameter.favorite_colors2;
  var favorite_colors3 = e.parameter.favorite_colors3;
  var favorite_colors4 = e.parameter.favorite_colors4;
  var dest = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
  var subject = 'New form response';
  var body = 'A new form was completed \n' +
    'Name: ' + name +
      '\nEmail: ' + email +
        '\nFavorite Colors: \n' + favorite_colors1
        +'\n'+favorite_colors2
        +'\n'+favorite_colors3
        +'\n'+favorite_colors4
    MailApp.sendEmail(dest, subject, body);
}
```

You'd get all the checkBoxes results.

```
test with all 4 checked :
    A new form was completed
    Name: name test
    Email: @@@@@
    Favorite Colors:
    blue
    red
    yellow
    green
```

Comment: Thanks Serge for your suggestion. I might end up going that route. I thought there was a way to have a "group checkebox" option of sorts. Your approach should work for sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the value of your inputs are all set to the same thing:

```
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“blue”>Blue<br/>
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“blue”>Red<br/>
```

should return blue,blue.

try setting them to match the result you expect:

```
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“blue”>Blue<br/>
<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_colors” value=“red”>Red<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks gardni for your help. The sample code that I posted was not accurate (updated now). The actual code has the right values. I still get only one value back if multiple checkboxes are selected. It seems like it picks the first one that it's checked. It's like e.parameter.favorite_colors is only storing the first checked checkbox only.

Comment: in that case you will need to either have separate inputs:
`<input type=“checkbox” name=“favorite_color_blue” value=“blue”>Blue<br/>` or loop through them

Comment: Would I loop through them when I retrieve them from e.parameter.favorite_colors? or do I have to loop through them when doing the post and then when retrieving the data as well. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps there is no way to loop through them. This post might be related to having multiple options https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=959

Comment: there does seem to be a lot of discussion about it, so i dont see why it wouldn't be possible, have you tried looking at some examples like this http://www.ryerson.ca/JavaScript/lectures/forms/boxes.html and adapting to your code?